# Replacing brake system on a bike

Tags: brakes

Is it possible to change the braking system from rim brakes to rotary. I want to replace them because I hate how after a while the pads wear out and I need to replace it so I think the rotary might be better. What would I need to do?

Comment: What kind of brakes does your bike have now? A picture and description would help a lot. Do you mean that you have some type of *rim* brakes (pads grab the wheel near the tire) and you're thinking about changing the bike to *disc* brakes (pads grab a rotor/disc near the center of the wheel)? Do you mean drum/roller/coaster brakes (brake inside the hub of the wheel)?

Comment: Yes, I have rim brakes. I've never heard of drum/roller/coaster brakes but anything better and the cheaper of the 2.

Comment: You must realise that _all_ brakes work by friction, so to stop the brakes themselves being destroyed, have a 'sacrificial' layer for a braking surface.  This means _all_ brakes have pads that need changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most practical solution would be to upgrade your brake pads. They may seem expensive, but both [Koolstop](http://www.koolstop.com/english/rim_pads.html) and [SwissStop](http://www.swissstop.ch) work pretty good. Search around, there are many online sellers.

You can see a significant change in brake performance with the right pads installed.

Comment: Very good idea I think i'll just get better brakes.

Answer (score 6):

In general, you can't replace rim brakes with hub or disk brakes unless the frame is designed for that.  In particular, hub or rim brakes place too much stress on the front fork unless the fork is designed for them.  You're probably better off buying a new bike with the "right" (for you) brakes factory-installed.

But I'm surprised that you have so much trouble with rim brakes.  I just had my rim brake pads replaced for the first time last year, after putting about 10,000 miles on my current bike.

Comment: From experience, off road MTB in volcanic country the pads won't last more than a few 100km, but neither does the bike...... Sandy trails is another killer.

Comment: They aren't that bad I guess I just have to get better brakes.

Answer (score 0):

watch this video it does describe in details the process

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. [We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please use the [edit] button to summarize the information is contained in the linked content within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.